# Add multiple text lines to an array

Tags: swift

Im trying to add to an already existing array by adding in over 1000 lines of code into an array. I need to add the code however don't want to manually add in the quotation and commas to each line. For example:

```
    var array = ["Hello there", "apples are yum", "oranges are not"]
```

Now I want to add

```
    Good evening
    I like ice cream
    Do you
```

How can I make the last three lines pass through a function to add the quotations and commas. Thanks. So the final array would appear as:

```
    var array = ["Hello there", "apples are yum", "oranges are not","Good evening", "I like ice cream", "Do you"]
```

Comment: You want to add each entire line as an object in the array? What do you want the output of that last block of text to be exactly?

Comment: Show your code. Where are you getting your input that you want to append? Appending strings is just `array.append(newString)`.

Comment: Are you asking how to put the <Line From File> into a format like "<Line from File>", "<Next Line From File>"?

Comment: The input is any snippet of text I want to put in an array. E.g a fact or quote from the internet. However I am too lazy to add quotations and commas to thousands of lines of text to allow it to pass in the array. Im sure there must be a way to pass a sentence like this; then have it output as a string with a concatenated comma on the end

Comment: Is this an app? Like you want it to output the array for you? Or do you want to be able to put it in your apps' source code? Because if it is the later, then you have to write a bash script.

Comment: Also, you really should look at why you are wanting to add hundred or thousands of lines of strings directly to your source code. You'll increase your app size very quickly when you do this. Why don't you more clearly explain what you are trying to do conceptually?

Comment: I'm knew to swift and programming so its a bit lame and simple. But it is for an app that generates another fact/quote/whatever when the user taps a button. The button press then cycles through the array printing one of the strings in an array at random

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Divide your `text` between newline characters such that each line is an object of an array then append the new and old arrays like so:

```
array += text.componentsSeparatedByString("\n") as [String]
```

Comment: Not sure what you quite mean. say I have an array: var array = ["A long sentence"] and want to add the text (without manually adding quotations or commas): another long sentence.             I Haven't been able to do so using this ling of code you provided

Comment: @vuss if `var array = ["Hello there", "apples are yum", "oranges are not"]` and `text = "Good evening\nI like ice cream\nDo you"` my answer will return:  `array == ["Hello there", "apples are yum", "oranges are not", "Good evening", "I like ice cream", "Do you"] ` Have you tried the code and printed the resulting array?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand the question this is what you are looking for:

```
var arr = ["Hello", "how", "are", "you"]

let str = "I am fine thank you"

arr += str.componentsSeparatedByString(" ")

// arr = ["Hello", "how", "are", "you", "I", "am", "fine", "thank", "you"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Very easy to do in Swift.

```
var array = ["Hello there", "apples are yum", "oranges are not"]
array.append("Good evening")
array.append("I like ice cream")
array.append("Do you")
```

After reading your question a little more, you do not need to add the `,` as the `,` is saying the next element in the array and is done for you when you use the `.append()` function.

The `"` is also not needed because this is saying that it is a string. So you want something like in a MyClass.swift file:

```
var array = ["Hello there", "apples are yum", "oranges are not"]

func addString(stringToAdd: String)->void{
this.array.append(stringToAdd)
}
```

So when you call this function from a different class, you do something like:

```
let aClass: MyClass = MyClass()
aClass.addString("Good evening")
etc...
```

Comment: Would Still need to manually type in each string. Im trying to avoid this as I have over 1000 lines to add. Therefore would need to append my array 1000+ times

Comment: Are you asking to put the strings into the source code? Or a better question is where are you getting the input?